# Model is null, even though populated model is passed in MVC 5 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using RedirectToAction to pass a new model to a different view.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(BlogViewModel vm)
    {
        vm.IsValid = ModelState.IsValid;
        vm.LoadDropDowns();
        vm.ProcessRequest();
        if (vm.IsValid)
        {
            // NOTE: Must clear the model state in order to bind
            //       the @Html helpers to the new model values
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in vm.ValidationErrors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
        if (vm.EventCommand == "viewblog") 
        {
            //Note: this is a DIFFERENT model than the one passed into this method
            var bpvm = new BlogPostViewModel
            {
                Blog = vm.Entity,
                IsBlogPostListAreaVisible = true
            };
            return RedirectToAction("BlogPost", "Blogs", bpvm);
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

On stepping through the code, variable bpvm is fully populated with the correct data. And yes vm.EventCommand == "viewblog" is true so it should fall down to  the redirect, which it does.

In the html

```
@model MachineryRestorations.Services.BlogService.BlogPostViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BlogPost";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <!-- BEGIN HIDDEN FIELDS AREA -->
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BlogPost.BlogPostId)
    @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EventArgument)*@
    <!-- END HIDDEN FIELDS AREA -->
    if (Model.IsBlogPostListAreaVisible)
    {
       <!-- code removed for brevity -->
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
And the code in the controller

```
public ActionResult BlogPost(BlogPostViewModel bpvm)
{
    return View(bpvm);
}
```

I am getting an error on Model.IsBlogPostListAreaVisible, this is due to the fact that with a breakpoint on the BeginForm, I see that Model is null. How is that when I'm passing it a perfectly valid model?

Comment: Have you tried `@if(Model.IsBlogPostListAreaVisible)` ?

Comment: You've missed out the actual action here - the code you've posted is for your view.  Perhaps your action isn't passing the model across to the view correctly?

Comment: @James Thorpe...see edit in OP above

Comment: If you break within `BlogPost` itself, is `bpvm` populated there, or also `null`?

Comment: @James Thorpe....good thought, tested that..The code is hitting my breakpoint in the page at HtmlBeginForm, BEFORE it is hitting the BlogPost ActionResult how is that possible? It shouldn't even know about opening that page without the model.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning back BlogViewModel not BlogPostViewModel. If

> if (vm.EventCommand == "viewblog")

is correct then return RedirectToAction("BlogPost", "Blogs", bpvm); only Redirects to **Action** which we're not seeing inner code

Comment: may be not populating BlogPost in the model can cause null error on @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BlogPost.BlogPostId) . I can't think something else without debugging,sorry

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ViewModel ***BlogPostViewModel*** is populated in the action method you're redirecting to. I think it should be ***BlogPost(BlogPostViewModel vm)***.